# Serving GridFS files with pyramid

Tags: python, nginx, pyramid, gridfs

I am wondering what is the best and possibly easiest way to serve files from GridFS using Pyramid. I use nginx as a proxy server (for ssl) and waitress as my application server.

The file types I need to be able to serve are the following: mp3, pdf, jpg, png

The files should be accessible through the following url "/files/{userid}/{filename}"

Right now the files are opened by the right application on client-side because I explicitly set the content-type in my code like so:

```
if filename[-3:] == "pdf":
    response = Response(content_type='application/pdf')

elif filename[-3:] in ["jpg", "png"]:
    response = Response(content_type='image/*')

elif filename[-3:] in ["mp3"]:
    response = Response(content_type='audio/mp3')

else:
    response = Response(content_type="application/*")

response.app_iter = file   #file is a GridFS file object
return response
```

The only thing is that I can't stream the mp3s properly. I use [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) to play them. They open up and play but no track length is shown and I can't seek them. I know it has something to do with the "accept-ranges" property but I can't seem to set it right. Does it have to do with nginx or waitress? Or am I just not setting the header correctly?

I would like to use something as easy as `return FileResponse(file)` like specified [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileResponse) but my file does not come from the filesystem directly... Is there a plug and play way to make this work?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would try the FileIter http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.FileIter

Comment: Thank you Tom. I tried with FileIter and while setting the content_length of the response. That way I at least have the length of the track that shows in my player, but I still can't seek the file. I checked the headers of the response, and I get a status 200, when I should get 206 - Partial Content. That is why I am wandering if my application server does its job right. I was mistaken, I use waitress to serve my pyramid app (I corrected my question above). It is not completly solved, but still is better than before! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on this [blog](http://blog.abourget.net/2011/3/23/new-and-hot-part-5-mongodb-integration/).

The idea is to use a patched `DataApp` from `paste.fileapp`. All the details are in the post, and now my app behaves just like I want!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem without the paste dependency in Pyramid 1.4, Python 3.

It seems that the attribute "conditional_response=True" and the "content_length" is important:

```
f = request.db.fs.files.find_one( { 'filename':filename, 'metadata.bucket': bucket } )

fs = gridfs.GridFS( request.db )

with fs.get( f.get( '_id') ) as gridout:
    response = Response(content_type=gridout.content_type,body_file=gridout,conditional_response=True)
    response.content_length = f.get('length')
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (using Pyramid 1.5.7 on Python 2.7):

```
fs = GridFS(request.db, 'MyFileCollection')
grid_out = fs.get(file_id)

response = request.response
response.app_iter = FileIter(grid_out)
response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % grid_out.name

return response
```